# Printing out Color

Tags: java, colors

```
package com.mycompany.advent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.\*;

public class Advent {
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\\u001B\[0m";
// Declaring the color
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\\u001B\[33m";

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
         Random rand = new Random(); 
         
         //game variables
        String[] enemies = {" Snake"," Gorilla"," Warrior"," Assasian"};
        int maxEnemyHealth=75;
        int enemyAttackDamage=25;
        int health=100;
        int attackDamage=50;
        int healthPotions=3;
        int healthPotionHealAmount = 30;
        int healthPotionDropChance = 50;//percentage
        int counter = 0;
        
        boolean running =true;
        
        System.out.println("░░░░░██╗██╗░░░██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░██╗░░░░░███████╗  ███╗░░░███╗░█████╗░██████╗░███╗░░██╗███████╗░██████╗░██████╗\n" +
                           "░░░░░██║██║░░░██║████╗░██║██╔════╝░██║░░░░░██╔════╝  ████╗░████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔════╝██╔════╝\n" +
                           "░░░░░██║██║░░░██║██╔██╗██║██║░░██╗░██║░░░░░█████╗░░  ██╔████╔██║███████║██║░░██║██╔██╗██║█████╗░░╚█████╗░╚█████╗░\n" +
                           "██╗░░██║██║░░░██║██║╚████║██║░░╚██╗██║░░░░░██╔══╝░░  ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║██║░░██║██║╚████║██╔══╝░░░╚═══██╗░╚═══██╗\n" +
                           "╚█████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║░╚███║╚██████╔╝███████╗███████╗  ██║░╚═╝░██║██║░░██║██████╔╝██║░╚███║███████╗██████╔╝██████╔╝\n" +
                           "░╚════╝░░╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚══════╝  ╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚══╝╚══════╝╚═════╝░╚═════╝░");
        
        
        GAME:
            while(running) {
                System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW + "╭━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━┳━━╮\n" +
                                                         "╰━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━┻━━╯" + ANSI_RESET);
```

Im trying to print color in my terminal, but it won't let me, I put it inside the class, but outside of the main method and it doesn't show any errors, but when I do press play, It does not print the color.

Comment: Why are you printing in a tight loop?

Comment: It's not the full code, I have more to it. I just don't know why the color won't work

Comment: You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you double quoting the "ANSI" strings?

Comment: `final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
 final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";`